# ToLower() in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest spiking CPU and bombing app

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

Hoping someone can shed some light on this issue we are having because I'm at a loss here.

First, a little background:

I rewrote the URL rewriting for our application and implemented it a couple of weeks ago. I did this using `Application_BeginRequest()` in the `global.asax` file and everything was fine with our application except for a small oversight I had made. When I'm rewriting the URLs I'm simply checking for the existence of certain keywords in the path that the user requests and then rewriting the path accordingly. Pretty straight forward stuff, not inventing the wheel here. Dry code, really. However, the text I'm checking for is all lowercase while the path may come in with different cases.

For instance:

```
string sPath = Request.Url.ToString();
sPath = sPath.Replace(Request.Url.Scheme + "://", "")
            .Replace(Request.Url.Host, "");
if (sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/')[0].Contains("reports") && sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/').Length > 2) {
            string[] aVariables = sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/');
            Context.RewritePath("/app/reports/report-logon.aspx?iLanguageID=" + aVariables[1] + "&sEventCode=" + aVariables[2]);
}
```

...if someone enters the pages as /Reports/, the rule will not match and they will receive a 404 error as a result.

Simple to fix, though, I thought. One only needs to force the requested path string to lowercase so that anything I attempt to match against it will be looking at a lowercase version of the requested path, and match successfully in cases such as the above. So I adjusted the code to read:

```
    string sPath = Request.Url.ToString();
    sPath = sPath.Replace(Request.Url.Scheme + "://", "")
                .Replace(Request.Url.Host, "");
    sPath = sPath.ToLower(); // <--- New line
    if (sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/')[0].Contains("reports") && sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/').Length > 2) {
                string[] aVariables = sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/');
                Context.RewritePath("/app/reports/report-logon.aspx?iLanguageID=" + aVariables[1] + "&sEventCode=" + aVariables[2]);
    }
```

With this fix, when I request any URL that matches against the URL rewriting, however, the CPU on the server spikes to 100% and my entire application crashes. I take out `.ToLower()`, kill the app pool, and the application is perfectly fine again.

Am I missing something here!?!? What gives? Why does such a simple method cause my application to explode? .ToLower() works everywhere else in our application, and although I'm not using it *extensively*, I am using it quite successfully in other places around the application.

Comment: It is not related to your problem, but you should store `sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/')` in a variable instead of computing it three times. Just saying.

Comment: @KooKiz Point well received. Thanks, I will make that change.

Comment: For that matter, if someone types in the wrong URI, then 404 is appropriate. If they type the wrong URI but you can work out with competence what they meant, 301 is the best approach. This way you just have thousands of URIs that mean the same thing. As to the reason, are you absolutely sure you have no typos in the original. I've done this in the past with typos that led to me calling properties when I meant to deal with a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly why ToLower would cause this (only thing I can think of is that it is modifying request.url, which sends asp.net into a frenzy), but there is an easy fix: use an ignorecase comparison rather than converting everything tolower.

Change:

```
sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/')[0].Contains("reports")
```

to:

```
sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/')[0].IndexOf("reports",  StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
```

and remove your ToLower logic.

Comment: @competent_tech - I thought the same regarding modifying request.url and the possibility of it throwing .net into a frenzy. Almost looks like an endless loop when it happens, so almost as if I'm forcing the Requested Url to lowercase and it's being re-requested, then forced to lowercase, re-requested, etc; but since I'm assigning the value of Request.Url to a string variable, I wouldn't think that I'd be modifying Request.Url directly. None the less, I'll definitely take your suggestion. Looks like it should work. Will mess around with it tonight and see if my server dies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though I can't say why .toLower() is bringing your server down

Why dont you try it with indexOf

```
 if (sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/')[0].IndexOf("reports",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)>=0 && sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/').Length > 2)
      {
        string[] aVariables = sPath.TrimStart('/').TrimEnd('/').Split('/');
        Context.RewritePath("/app/reports/report-logon.aspx?iLanguageID=" + aVariables[1] + "&sEventCode=" + aVariables[2]);
      }
```